# Best practises on using i18n to translate server responses

Tags: node.js, i18next

I need a suggestion. I'm writing some APIs using express and nodejs. Given that in our frontend there are two available languages: english and italian, do I have to use i18n for my backend too so that my responses are already translated? Or is it better to translate those responses when the response arrives from the backend to the client?

What are the best practises here? I don't have much experience so I need to ask this.

Comment: If you need more than just translating errors via api, have a look at: https://locize.com/blog/how-does-server-side-internationalization-look-like/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return additional `error_key` from API with translation key:

```json
{
    "error": "No brains found",
    "error_i18n": "error.brains.404"
}
```

This approach will help if you have feature to switch language while showing error messages - error does not have to be re-thrown to translate to other language *and* you can write same error to logs for debugging

Comment: I'm approaching the error following your suggestion. Thank you